# Language not declared Ideally

Tags: html, .htaccess, lang

I've been running some tests on my website in regards to the Google webmaster guidelines.

To my surprise it states that I'm not declaring my language ideally. Upon checking my HTML, I have the following within it:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
```

Am I stating the language incorrectly? As I thought this was correct...

Comment: There was no link providing additional explanation? (It could be that the ideal format is `en-US`, `en-GB` and the like, but I don't know for sure.)

Comment: That didn't work I'm afraid. I'm sorry that I couldn't provide more information. The only message I received was "Language not declared Ideally"

Comment: I would try `en-US` or `en-GB` (or whatever) and run it again.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka웃, sadly that did not fix it.

Comment: Hmm. Check out the recommendations in https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.en

Comment: Thank you @Pekka웃, I will take a look now :) I appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a fix to this problem, as I mentioned when I was trying to declare the language via HTML it just would not work.

So I used `.htaccess` to fix the problem by sending custom headers:

```
Header set Content-Language "en-GB"
```