# How to add content-language for a single page in http header

Tags: http-headers, content-type, multilingual, lang

**My index page is tri-lingual...** in this scenario, W3 informs us that the original 'ID solution' was dropped, without a replacement......

W3 does suggest the use of HTTP headers, but fails to explain how this is accomplished.

Can stackoverflow solve this problem?

**Background**

W3 suggests that this code is not good/should not be used:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="de, fr, en">
```

However, they then say that there is nothing to replace it:

> One implication of HTML5 dropping the meta element for declaring
>   language is that there is now no obvious way to provide metadata about
>   the document inside the document itself.

**That's a painful statement**, but... they then go on to suggest that "content-language" should be specified in a HTTP header.

> This information is associated with a particular page by settings on
>   the server or by server-side scripting.

Fantastic... they even show a typical example... great!

```
HTTP/1.1·200·OK
Date:·Sat,·23·Jul·2011·07:28:50·GMT
Server:·Apache/2
Content-Location:·qa-http-and-lang.en.php
Vary:·negotiate,accept-language,Accept-Encoding
TCN:·choice
P3P:·policyref="http://www.w3.org/2001/05/P3P/p3p.xml"
Connection:·close
Transfer-Encoding:·chunked
Content-Type:·text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language:·en
```

But where is this file... and why is this character "·" used?

Why not use comma separated en, fr, de ?

**Rant (after hours of researching):**

If website programmers are advised not to use in-doc programming, it would be better if we were told exactly how to edit the HTTP header for any given page.

**Therefore the question is simple?**

Using CPanel, or Filezilla (and perhaps notepad++)... How do I modify the HTTP header for index.html to show that it contains English, French, German?

Note: I am currently using the bad code PLUS 'lang tags' eg:

```
<li lang="fr">
```

I'm trying to do what is right, but after looking on 'HTTP header help-sites', I never once found a statement re:

- Exact file location
- Filename and extension

Can anybody help solve this mystery?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't manage to find this, the HTTP Headers are what you are after as they describe the language you are expecting your target audience to use, and it can be multiple languages. HTTP Headers are set on your web server and apply to every page in your website.

If you are using **Apache** find the .htaccess file and add something along the lines of:

```
Header set Content-Language "en"
```

If you are using **IIS** then:

1. navigate to your website in the IIS GUI
2. double-click 'Http Response headers'
3. click 'Add...'
4. the name is Content-Language, the value is the language you want to use, for example use en for any kind of English, use commas to seperate multiple
5. Click OK

I got most of my info from here:

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations#metadata

Here is a list of the subtags you can use:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry

thickguru supplied the .htaccess solution above, many thanks, his answer is here:
[Language not declared Ideally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273839/language-not-declared-ideally)

Comment: Thanks Jono... I ended up using link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-FR" etc.
.. it's cumbersome to create, with each page version linking to each page version... apparently google will now deliver the correct version for the region and the browser language.